# How to know if tableview row is odd or even agnostic of the section it is in

Tags: ios, objective-c, listview, tableview

I am making an application where I am getting a user's phone book and displaying it in a list view. I am breaking the phone book into sections sorted by their name. I want to alternate rows by even and odds HOWEVER the problem is the indexPath.row resets back to zero if a new section starts. I am trying to get whetehr it is an odd or even row AGNOSTIC of the section it is in
i tried

```
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell
    forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    if(switcher == 0)
    {
     switcher = 1;
    }
     else
     {
      switcher = 0;
     }
}
```

hoping that the odds even selector would change every time a new cell will be displayed.
THIS ALMOST works however sometimes if i stop and start scrolling again I WILL GET zero twice or 1 twice (it is not perfect).

Thank you in advance!
[I added a picture for the current result and another for the desired result[image: ][1]]

Comment: add the counts of the previous sections to your current index

Comment: What is switcher in this instance?

Comment: switcher is an int which when the view loads I make zero.. the point is to switch it to be 1 and 0 because I make my background color change if the "switcher" is odd or even. as a odds evens selector @soulshined

Comment: @Fonix i Don't think that is viable. I can see that causing lag as it would be very computational heavy to have to do this each time a row is created...

Comment: Use this method instead of tableviewwilldisplaycell  -->(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: @KrunalDarji I am already? look at my code example

Comment: @Dnaso, but surely you know how big your sections are because of your data structure for populating the rows/sections? just find out the length of your arrays...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the number of rows that come in all the sections before the given section. Then you can do a modulus operation to determine if it is even or odd. You can use this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to change the color based on `isOdd`.

```
NSUInteger row = indexPath.row;
for (int i = 0; i < indexPath.section; i++) {
    row += [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:i];
}
BOOL isOdd = row % 2;  // if it is divisible by 2, this will be 0. if it isn't, it is 1
```

Comment: do you think that the is a "computational heavy" solution or should that work for say 200 rows or so?

Comment: There's one way to find out, haha. I would say no. This is simple add instructions with one divide at the end. CPUs are very good at doing this kind of thing. I don't think it will be a problem.